# Why does "word-definition" appear as a tag synonym?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

When tagging a question on English.SE, `[word-definition]` appear twice as a suggestion when `word-def` is entered.

> word-definition (8)
>   word-definition (s)

IIRC, the `(s)` indicates a tag synonym. Why does this happen when,

1) a tag cannot be a synonym of itself, and
2) `[word-definition]` has no synonyms at all?

Comment: do you mind posting on http://meta.stackoverflow.com ... this is a bug ..

Comment: I opened a [report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62763/tag-synonymous-appears-twice-in-the-auto-completition) on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed.